# Undefined variable error when the variable name is used in form filed

Tags: php

while  executing my code some times a warning message comes like use of undefined variable even if the variable name is being used properly in the form field.

```
<form method="post" id="" action"">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

$name=$_POST['name'];
```

even if the name is used in the form field warning message comes and i had to put @ in front of it

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

@$name=$_POST['name'];
}
```

why is is so can anyone help me out with it

Comment: The `@` operator in PHP supresses warnings. See [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: Who the hell is a Down Voter Has down voted every answer without a single comment about it :(

Comment: Sidenote: You're missing an `=` sign in `action""` so that won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason was you have not initialized $name variable and also $_POST['name'] not found until your form not submitted

so try to initialize variable first like

```
$name = '';
```

or

```
$name= (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '');
```

or

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
        $name=$_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not at all submitting your `<form>` using a submit button. and the action attribute has no `=`

Should be like ...

**`Your HTML form`**

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**`test.php`**

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
 echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `$name = (isset($_POST["name"])?$_POST["name"]:"");`